# How to change x axis (in order to be scaled) of a boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm new to R and i'm having some trouble in solving this problem.

I have the following table/dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to generate a boxplot like this one:

[image]

However, i want that the x-axis be scaled according to the labels 1000, 2000, 5000, etc.

So, i want that the distance between 1000 and 2000 be different from the distance between 50000 and 100000, since the exact distance is not the same.
Is it possible to do that in R?

Thank you everyone and have a nice day!

Comment: Could you use `dput(yourdf)` and provide sample  data rather than pictures. It'll make things easier for those willing to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to convert the data set in to this format, ie as integers in a column, rather than a header title?

```
# packages
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# data in ideal format
dt <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1,10,100), each=5),
                 y=runif(15))

# data that we have. Use reshape2::dcast to get data in to this format
dt$id <- rep(1:5, 3) 
dt_orig <- dcast(dt, id~x, value.var = "y")
dt_orig$id <- NULL
names(dt_orig) <- paste0("X", names(dt_orig))

# lets get back to dt, the ideal format :)
# melt puts it in (variable, value) form. Need to configure variable column
dt2 <- melt(dt_orig)

# firstly, remove X from the string
dt2$variable <- gsub("X", "", dt2$variable)

# almost there, can see we have a character, but need it to be an integer
class(dt2$variable)
dt2$variable <- as.integer(dt2$variable)

# boxplot with variable X axis
ggplot(dt2, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=variable)) + geom_boxplot() + theme_minimal()
```

Base way of re-shaping data: https://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

Comment: still couldn't do it :/ Tried to transpose the dataframe turning the header as column but didn't work.

Comment: no worries :). I have amended my answer to show how you can re-work and play with the data